# Hierarchical Grid in Kendo UI with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, kendo-ui

I am implementing 3 level hierarchy grid using the Kendo UI MVC controls. At First level there will be Users Roles, expanding users Roles will show all the Features defined for that role and expanding features will show all the Features Actions that are defined for that features.

At Feature and Features Action grid there will be checkboxes in the first column so that user checks the checkboxes to assigned the feature actions to the features and features to User Roles. Below the Feature Action grid there will be Submit button to Save the data(all the features actions and features assigned to the Roles by checking the checkboxes).

Now, I have few questions regarding this.

1. How to submit the Features and Features Actions grid data model to my Action method on click of Submit button?
2. I want if any of the features checkboxe is checked then all the feature actions will gets checked by default?
3. Is it possible to use the default Save Changes button of the kendo UI grid in hierarchy grid.I tried to implement this by using the toolbar.Save() button but button does not shows up in the grid.

Comment: When you say "Kento UI MVC", do you means "Kendo UI with ASP.NET MVC"?

Comment: Yes I am using Kendo UI with Aps.net MVC controls.